# Image rotating 90 degrees when uploaded from mobile? PHP

Tags: php, html, live

I have a site where users can upload photos from mobile, but all the photos that are uploaded from mobiles, show 90 degrees to the left when upload. Live site is `www.uneraportoj.com`. I now the problem is the exeif but i tried using a plugin but is not working. Any help is recommended.

Share script code is:

```
 <?php

    include_once('help.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        $posted = $_POST['posted'];
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        $rand = rand(1,1000000);

        if(empty($title)){
            echo "Titulli eshte bosh.";
        }else if(empty($content)){
            echo "Permbajtja eshte bosh.";
        }else if(empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){
            echo "Imazhi eshte bosh.";
        }else if (
                ($_FILES['image']['type'] == 'image/gif') 
                || ($_FILES['image']['type'] == 'image/jpeg') 
                || ($_FILES['image']['type'] == 'image/pjpeg') 
                || ($_FILES['image']['type'] == 'image/png') 
                && ($_FILES['image']['size'] < 200000)
                ){

                    $part = $rand.'_'.$_FILES['image']['name'];

                    if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0) {
                        echo "return code" . $_FILES['image']['error'];

                        //Code from plugin start
                        if($_FILES['image']){
                            // If the image is jpg and has orientation data, make sure we orientate correctly before uploading
                            if($image->exif('Orientation'))
                                $image = orientate($image, $image->exif('Orientation'));
                        }

                    }else if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'images/'. $part.'')){

                        if(empty($posted)){
                            $posted = 'Anonim';
                        }

                        $sql = "INSERT INTO ***(title, content, date, image, posted, ip) VALUES (:title, :content, :date, :image, :posted, :ip)";
                        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
                        $results = $query->execute(array(
                            ':title' => htmlentities ($title),
                            ':content' => htmlentities ($content),
                            ':date' => $date,
                            ':image' => $part,
                            ':posted' => htmlentities ($posted),
                            ':ip' => $ip
                        ));
                        echo "<div id='ok'>Lajmi u raportua me sukses. Kontrollojeni <a href='index.php'>ketu</a> .</div>";

                    }
                }else{
                    echo "<div id='ok'>Imazhi nuk eshte i sakte. (Vetem jpg/png)</div>";
                }

    }
?>
```

Plugin code :

```
    <?php /**
 * Orientate an image, based on its exif rotation state
 * 
 * @param  Intervention\Image\Image $image
 * @param  integer $orientation Image exif orientation
 * @return Intervention\Image\Image
 */

 $image = $_FILES['image'];

function orientate($image, $orientation)
{
    switch ($orientation) {

        // 888888
        // 88    
        // 8888  
        // 88    
        // 88    
        case 1:
            return $image;

        // 888888
        //     88
        //   8888
        //     88
        //     88
        case 2:
            return $image->flip('h');


        //     88
        //     88
        //   8888
        //     88
        // 888888
        case 3:
            return $image->rotate(180);

        // 88    
        // 88    
        // 8888  
        // 88
        // 888888
        case 4:
            return $image->rotate(180)->flip('h');

        // 8888888888
        // 88  88    
        // 88        
        case 5:
            return $image->rotate(-90)->flip('h');

        // 88        
        // 88  88    
        // 8888888888
        case 6:
            return $image->rotate(-90);

        //         88
        //     88  88
        // 8888888888
        case 7:
            return $image->rotate(-90)->flip('v');

        // 8888888888
        //     88  88
        //         88
        case 8:
            return $image->rotate(90);

        default:
            return $image;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I need to mention that you should be using `htmlspecialchars()` on all `$_POST` data, e.g. `$title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);`  As you have it right now, you are under a HUGE security threat.

Answer (score 1):

I found this youtube video to be super helpful on image oriantaion with exif data
check it out 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjHSgGFqAtE

```
print 'exif orientation';

$original_filename = 'car1.jpg';
$exif_data = exif_read_data($original_filename);

// displays exif data
// print '<pre>';
// print_r($exif_data);
// print '<pre>';


$orientation = orientation($exif_data);
$degrees = orientation_flag($orientation);
print '<pre>';
print_r($orientation);
print '</pre>';

print '<pre>';
print_r($degrees);
print '</pre>';

$image_data = imagecreatefromjpeg($original_filename);
$image_rotate = imagerotate($image_data, $degrees, 0);

$rotated_filename = 'rotated_' . $original_filename;
imagejpeg($image_rotate, $rotated_filename);
imagedestroy($image_data);
imagedestroy($image_rotate);


// finds orientation value in exif data
function orientation($exif_data) {
  // search array for orientation
  foreach($exif_data as $key => $val) {
    // print '<pre>';
    // print_r($key);
    // print '<pre>';
    if(strtolower($key) == 'orientation') {
      return $val;
    }
  }
}


// gets orientation data and returns degrees needed for rotation
function orientation_flag($orientation) {
 switch($orientation):
  case 1:
    return 0;
  case 8:
    return 90;
  case 3:
    return 180;
  case 6:
    return 270;
  endswitch;
 }

?>


 <img src="car1.jpg" width="400"/>
 <br>
 <img src="rotated_car1.jpg" width="400"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your function call under the if(error) statement, meaning it will only rotate if there is an error. Place it after your image has passed the error checks and you have moved it to the final location.

```
                if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0) {
                    echo "return code" . $_FILES['image']['error'];

                }else if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']{'tmp_name'],'images/'. $part.'')){

                    if(file_exists('images/'. $part.'')){
                       /* read exif data (returns it as an array) */
                       $exif_read = exif_read_data('images/'. $part.'');

                       /* if exif contains orientation property (some images don't) */
                       if(!empty($exif_read['Orientation'])){
                            $orientation_data = $exif_read['Orientation'];
                            $image = orientate($image, $Orientation_data);
                    }
```

**Edit:**

I copied and pasted the exact code that I am using for image uploading. For what I'm doing, I only have to worry about orientations 3, 6, and 8, but you can add the rest if you think you'll need them. Use PHP's imageflip() function after imagerotate() (read how to use that [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageflip.php))

```
<?php

require("../db_credentials.php");

if($_FILES['file']['name']){
  $name = htmlspecialchars($_FILES['file']['name']);
  $ext = end((explode(".", $name)));
  $ext = strtolower($ext);

  //if no errors...
  if(!$_FILES['file']['error']){
    //now is the time to modify the future file name and validate the file
    $new_file_name = date('ymdHisu'). ".". $ext;

    if($_FILES['file']['size'] > (6144000)){
      $valid_file = false;
      echo 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';
    }
    elseif($ext !== "jpg" && $ext !== "png" && $ext !== "jpeg" && $ext != "gif" && $ext !== "bmp") {
      $valid_file = false;
      echo "Your file must be in jpg, jpeg, png, gif, or bmp formats.";
    }
    else{
      $valid_file = true;
    }

    //if the file has passed the test
    if($valid_file){
      //move it to where we want it to be
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'images/'.$new_file_name);

      $exif_read = exif_read_data("images/".$new_file_name);
      if(!empty($exif_read['Orientation'])){
        $orientation_data = exif_read_data("images/".$new_file_name)['Orientation'];
      }
      if(isset($orientation_data) && $orientation_data !== 1){
    $path = "../images/". $new_file_name;
        $buffer = ImageCreateFromJPEG($path);
       $exif = exif_read_data($path);
        if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])){
          switch($exif['Orientation']){
            case 8:
              $buffer = imagerotate($buffer,90,0);
              break;
            case 3:
              $buffer = imagerotate($buffer,180,0);
              break;
            case 6:
              $buffer = imagerotate($buffer,-90,0);
              break;
          }
          imagejpeg($buffer, $path, 90);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //if there is an error...
  else
  {
    //set that to be the returned message
    echo 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['file']['error'];
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Hello, I get the following error : ' Fatal error: Call to a member function exif() on a non-object in /home/henrimma/public_html/php/shareScript.php on line 37 ' Thanks for your help

Comment: I missed that the first time. I updated my answer with bit of code from a software that I wrote and use. The problem is the code was trying to call a function 'exif()', which doesn't exist. The function to read exif data is 'exif_read_data()', and it returns all the data as an array. You can read more about this at http://php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php

Comment: What problem are you having? What error is it returning?

Comment: I edited my answer and added the full code I am using.

Comment: I cant seem to have it work for me. Can we email each other maybe you can have access ob my site and try to fix this. Thanks @frostycoles

Comment: What problems are you having? Is it returning any errors, or just sending back a blank page without doing anything? The above code is working for me without throwing any errors or warnings. Also understand that I work full time, and therefore this is all I'm capable of giving. If you tell me what errors you're getting, I can maybe walk you through resolving them.